# Streaming a collection will give an error when document created with TimeStamp Field

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
> StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(dirty, state:
> _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#f407c): The method
> 'toDate' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: toDate()

On pressing the FAB a doc will be created with a field of firebase timestamp.

Now on Streaming the collection. I get this error for split a split second. What I think the problem is.. Is that the document gets created first and then it gets updated with timestamp. Causing an error at the instance the doc is created.

[image]

```
class XYZ extends StatelessWidget {
  const XYZ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Test').add({'time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
          },
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Test').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) return Center();

            snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
              print(doc.data()['time'].toDate());
            });

            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Is this the behavior of firestore? Or I have made a wrong implementation in my code?**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your mistake is using `toDate()` before casting "TimeStamp" class.

Please try below lines;

```dart
snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
final timestamp = doc.data()['time'] as Timestamp;
final dateTime = timestamp.toDate();
print('Date: ${dateTime}');
});
```